# How to select entire symbols in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know how to traverse / select entire symbols in Eclipse editors?

For example if a code line has the symbol "Util_Select_Group" it takes no less than 5 Ctrl+Right to traverse the symbol from left to right.  (It stops before and after '_')  (Same goes while selecting with Ctrl+Shift+Right)  Drives me nuts!

I'm used to Visual Studio where entire symbols are traversed in one keystroke.  I have looked in all settings but to no avail.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Check the Edit menu for a way to Expand the Selection.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Preferences in General > Keys. See what key strokes 'Select Next Element' is bound to. There may be several different bindings for different editors so make sure you choose the binding for the editor you are using.

If you are using a Mac then double click also works but I think this may be specific to Macs.

Comment: Hi greg-449!  Thanks very much for taking the time... this just might do it!  I'll try it and report if it works.  Many thanks! :)

Comment: I've tried and it didn't work :-(  There is a 'Select Next C/C++ Element' but even if I set its editor from C/C++ to generic 'Editing Text' it does not take hold in the source code I'm editing (Python with PyDev)